# 'Wracked with" or "wracked by"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, by-with

Which is considered (more) correct: *wracked **by** [X]* or *wracked **with** [X]*?

Example sentences:

> He is wracked with grief.
>
> He is wracked by grief.

The [Cambridge definition of *wrack*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wrack) contains examples of historical use of both forms.

Thanks!

(Apologies if this has already been asked; I searched first, but only saw the more common question of *rack* versus *wrack*.)

Comment: Hello, mogtek. CD would not give examples it considered incorrect. [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wracked+with+guilt%2Cwracked+by+guilt&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) show that 'with' is used far more commonly nowadays, though in 1944 apparently the two choices were equally popular.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're absolutely right re: CD. You've helped me realize I should have asked which (if either) is considered more  appropriate to use now. From your Google ngrams search, sounds like 'with' is the answer? (Thanks also for the link to ngrams, I'll make sure to check that in future)

Comment: It's quite true that ***with*** is now the "preferred" preposition between ***wracked*** and ***guilt***. But there's nothing remotely "unidiomatic" about either of them. On the other hand, when it comes to near-synonymous ***flushed*** and ***emboldened*** before ***success***, it's practically *always* [***emboldened by success***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=emboldened+by+success%2Cemboldened+with+success&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)...

Comment: ...and practically always [***flushed with success***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flushed+by+success%2Cflushed+with+success&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) That kinda suggests there aren't many useful "patterns" one could learn in this area.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Very good point. Before I asked here, I considered several other common adjective+preposition combinations (*flushed with* being one of them), and couldn't find a pattern.

Comment: mogtek: Per my comment under @KTM's answer, I'm not convinced it's worth committing the (*potential*, not inevitable) subtle *semantic* distinction to memory. Most people whose text you're likely to read or hear (or who are likely to read / hear *your* utterances) probably won't make or appreciate the distinction anyway. But slight though it is, the distinction is real (to some of us), so I at least have voted to reopen what I think was an unduly hastily closevoted question.

Comment: This question was closed because I didn't check Google n-grams first, right? I admit I only scanned the list of references at first; I see n-grams on there now. (Sorry, the answer is probably as obvious as it seems, but I want to make sure I understand what I did wrong)

Comment: I don't know why your question was closed; it's possible that it seems, to some users, something too obvious for this site. (I disagree.) However, your question is in review to be reopened, if one more person votes to reopen, your question will be answerable again. Editing to link some ngrams may help, but I have a feeling your question will be reopened anyway :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just commented on KTM's answer. While I think you're right, and I did want to know which option is now most commonly used, FWIW I'm also curious about what might make sense from a language logic perspective.

Comment: @Heartspring, mogtek: Expecting querents to do "prior research" involving Google Grams seems a bit extreme for a question like this. At the end of the day, any slight usage distinction here probably just turns on the (minimal) semantic difference between ***with** ("correlative")* vs ***by** ("causative")*. And it's probably more relevant as something for people *fluent* in English to ponder here on ELU, rather than for *learners* on ELL to take on board. But we always have to bear in mind that language (*especially* English?) isn't necessarily amenable to "logical" dissection / explanation.

Comment: The closure of this question (and its reopening, and many others) ties into the current discussion on Meta: [Replacing our "research" close reason](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15694/191178). Please check it out, especially if you've been close voting questions. (cc @EdwinAshworth)

Answer (score 6):

The distinction is subtle, and it's even possible that it's only illusory, but in the examples given by Cambridge it seems that "wracked by" is followed by the agent of ruin whereas "wracked with" is followed by the content of agony.

So we have:

- "wracked **by** civil war"
- "wracked **by** a titanic struggle"
- "wracked **by** communal riots"

In these examples, the agent may not be a part of the result -- the war and rioting may be over, but the ruin remains.

On the other hand:

- "wracked **with** pain"
- "wracked **with** rheumatism"

Here, but for the pain and sickness there would be a whole person.

- "wracked **by** famine."

This example shows the weakness of the distinction. "Wracked **with** famine" sounds identical, but then again, famine is the cause of famine...

In your example, I would probably use "wracked with grief" to describe someone who was currently grieving and "wracked by grief" to describe someone, say, whose life had been destroyed by past grief.

Comment: I also Ngrammed this one. It's interesting that the recent divergence seems to come from British usage rather than American

Comment: I'm not allowed to comment yet except on my own entries. What is the consensus for closing this question? It's an interesting and subtly flavored distinction that I, a native English speaker, had never before considered.
Stack Exchange is getting way too fierce...

Comment: I understand perfectly well the fine distinction you're making here, and without a doubt at least *some* speakers / writers would implement it in their own speech / writing. But far more *won't*, and it's worth noting that the most common noun after both ***wracked with*** and ***wracked by*** is ***guilt***. That fact alone is enough to convince me that anyone who seeks to improve their command of English using sites like this will probably just end up confusing themselves with pointless details that only *marginally* reflect reality.

Comment: I feel very conflicted by what you just said, but then I just got here.

Just for my own clarity, if the question had been "what is the difference (if any)" instead of "which one is correct," would it have remained open?

Comment: No, I've decided that you're right. I'm answering a question about "with" vs "by" and "wracked" is merely the accident.

Comment: I'm not criticizing you or your answer in any way, so please accept my apologies if that's how it comes across. I actually *agree* that there's a potential difference, exactly as you've pointed out. I'm just warning the OP that whereas (some) native speakers might be interested in such differences, for the most part there's no point in non-native Anglophone *learners* committing to memory a distinction that would almost never raise an eyebrow if it weren't honoured. But the wrong combinations of ***flushed / emboldened WITH/BY success*** will be *very* noticeable to many/most native speakers.

Comment: I didn't notice this at all; thanks for pointing it out! Although I did want to know specifically about *wracked by/with guilt*, and which form is more commonly used now, this potential distinction is very interesting. I really enjoy the subtleties in how we use English - I'm just useless at identifying them :-) While *famine* might not fit your pattern, could the distinction there be temporal? i.e. an area might be currently *wracked **with** famine*, or have been *wracked **by** famine* in the past?

Comment: (This would be similar to how your handling of *by/with* for *guilt*)

Comment: @FumbleFingers wracked with pain and by pain are also common.

Comment: @Lambie: True, but it's worth noting that whereas *wracked **with pain*** is the *second* most common word overall (after *wracked with guilt*) for that preposition, after *wracked **by...*** the first three most common words are ***a, the*** and the adjective ***civil...*** (no doubt modifying ***...war*** in most cases). *Wracked by **guilt*** is 4th in the list for that preposition, and ***...by pain*** doesn't appear until position #8. So they're definitely used somewhat differently, exactly as KTM says.

Comment: +1. Interesting and thoughtful answer. Welcome to EL&U, KTM.

Comment: @mogtek: The "distinction" (such as it is) isn't "temporal". It's what KTM and I are both saying (using different words) - ***with*** attaches better to *what is **experienced***, whereas ***by*** attaches better to *what **causes** the experience*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I apologize - I did understand that, but my comment was muddy. KTM's example referred to current versus past grief, and so I wondered whether, with examples such as famine, there could *also* be reason to choose between by and with based on when the event occurred. In retrospect, this would be handled by the preceding verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers These ngrams are really irrelevant, imo.

Comment: @FumbleFingers digression, but: "temporal" leads me to suspect I used the word incorrectly. I'll look into how I could have phrased that better.

Comment: @mogtek: Don't be put off by my "scare quotes". From your *...might be **currently** wracked with famine* OR ***...have been** wracked by famine **in the past*** it looks pretty obvious that's a valid word. Something to do with the passage of time, regardless of whether you were thinking past / present, continuous / temporary, or whatever. I'm just saying nothing like that has any direct relevance to the preposition choice.

Comment: You correctly note the difference, but at the moment you're just pointing out that Cambridge says so, which doesn't say much about how English works. I'd suggest expanding a bit on the underlying reasons (which is presumably just a result of what "by" and "with" means).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand, and genuinely appreciate your explanation